# Event is not triggered and Blazor component won't refresh

Tags: asp.net-core, events, blazor, blazor-client-side

I want to make my component refresh based on authorize change. Here is my component:

```
@inject IAuthService AuthService
@implements IDisposable

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Logged as: @Identity
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code
{
    private string Identity { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AuthService.RefreshRequested += StateHasChanged;
        Identity = $"{(await AuthService.GetClaimFromToken("sub"))?.Value} ({(await AuthService.GetClaimFromToken("unique_name"))?.Value})";
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        AuthService.RefreshRequested -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

and here is a part of my service:

```
    public class AuthService: IAuthService
    {
        // ...
        public event Action RefreshRequested;

        public async Task<RequestResponse> Token(LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            // some logic

            CallRequestRefresh();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestResponse>(result);
        }

        private void CallRequestRefresh()
        {
            RefreshRequested?.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

`Token(...)` method is used in other component. I don't know why in the mentioned component, `StateHasChanged` isn't triggered.

All I want to actually achieve is to provide some way to update `Identity` property, using given asynchronous method (`GetClaimFromToken`).

Comment: 1. I think you need put the `AuthService.RefreshRequested += StateHasChanged;` after the `Identity = $"....";`  2. Also, you have to make sure your component is right there and **NOT** disposed when someone invokes the `Token(...)` method

Comment: @itminus This is the shared component. It isn't disposed during the invocation of `Token(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve my issue. I couldn't use my service, because it wasn't registered as Singleton. I created a class `AppState` and registered it as Singleton:

```
    public class AppState
    {
        public event Action RefreshRequested;

        public void TriggerRefreshAction()
        {
            StateChanged();
        }

        private void StateChanged()
        {
            RefreshRequested?.Invoke();
            Console.WriteLine("State has changed");
        }
    }
```

and injected it to the component and `AuthService`. Also I needed to change some logic of my component as `StateHasChanged()` triggers `OnAfterRender/OnAfterRenderAsync`, which update my string `Identity` but won't change UI. Seems to work now, but I don't like the approach of updating value on UI:

```
@inject IAuthService AuthService
@inject AppState AppState
@implements IDisposable

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Logged as: @Identity
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code
{
    private string Identity { get; set; }
    private bool Refresh { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        await UpdateIdentity();
        AppState.RefreshRequested += RefreshComponent;
    }

    public void Dispose()
      => AppState.RefreshRequested -= RefreshComponent;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (Refresh)
        {
            await UpdateIdentity();
            Refresh = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    private async Task UpdateIdentity()
      => Identity = $"{(await AuthService.GetClaimFromToken("sub"))?.Value} ({(await AuthService.GetClaimFromToken("unique_name"))?.Value})";

    private void RefreshComponent()
    {
        Refresh = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

There must be a better solution.